# markdown - how do I display HTML?

Tags: markdown

I am trying to add a wiki page on GitHub that contains sample HTML but can't figure out how to  display the actual HTML, not try to render it.

I tried & lt; & gt;  and &lt; &lt; but then it renders it like

& lt;table& gt;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want display HTML as code sample. You can use formatting for [code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Code)

Examples:

````
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xs:schema>
```
````

Comment: For some reason on github ` was giving me strange results. Removing ALL ` and <pre><code> stuff and just indenting (not using tabs) the html 4 spaces caused it to render correctly. :/

Comment: dag nabbit, still no go for me, I would love an actual example as I want to show some XML on there without doing html escape junk

Answer (score 11):

Tip: You can also display 'inline' HTML by adding a single backtick:

```
`<html>`
```